# SQL SERVER (LINUX) – syspolicy_purge_history job failing step 3: Erase Phantom System Health Records

Tags: centos, database, sqlserver

No one out there seems to have an answer for this...everything is for windows and no help for those using linux to run SQL Server 2019.  Problem is that the 3rd step in this process is to run Powershell...since this is a windows item (not installed on linux by default), of course it will fail in linux.  You'd think MS would have thought of this but apparently not.  Any help or point in the right direction would be helpful.